# Rich snippets on product category page without AggregateRating

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data

In the past we used rich snippets on product category pages (filtered themed product list)

For this we listed from-to price. Description. Thumbs. Availability. And AggregateRating.

AggregateRating is no longer allowed. Or stated otherwise you can do it but then google will drop all your snippets.

That being said. Here is my question

What is the alternative to product category pages without! AggregateRating? (Not marking up individual products)

I mean I can share title, product count, lowest and highest price, availability, description, thumbs etc. all in snippets. How would this snippet look and does any one have experience with this?

Ok AggregateRating is not allowed. But it seems illogical that there now is no rich data at all when I read that google like snippets because they explain what is on the page.

Thanks!!

Comment: 1) Google [still documents](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews) that their Review snippet makes use of `AggregateRating`. 2) As far as I know, Google never offered a rich result for category pages. The Review rich results were/are about a single thing, not about a category of different things.

Answer (score 1):

You report in your question:

> AggregateRating is no longer allowed.

You are wrong. Google recommend to apply this property. Read more *Google search guides about* **[Reviews](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews)**. I assume that you had this markup with errors or with violations of Google's principles for this markup. 
Note the following requirements for this structured data:

> Single reviewer name needs to be **valid**. For example, "50% off until Saturday" is not a valid name for a reviewer.

Further in the chapter "*Review snippet definitions+Common review properties*":

> author - Person or Organization, **required**.

The reiewer’s name needs to be a valid name. A good solution for marking the review author will be to link his legal name with his own link to the social network or personal / corporate website. 
Also the documentation specifies the types for this markup:

> You can supply ratings for the following content types:
>   * Local businesses + * Movies + * Books + * Music + * Products

The same information is in the documentation Google search guides about **[Products](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products)** informs:

> Reviewer’s name needs to be a valid name for a Person or Team For example, "James Smith" or"CNET Reviewers." By contrast, "50% off on Black Friday" is invalid.

Read more **[Local Reviews and Ratings of MOZ](https://moz.com/learn/seo/local-reviews)**.

To mark structured data for a list of product categories and / or for a list of products, you can use the property **[hasOfferCatalog](http://schema.org/hasOfferCatalog)**. This property was created to link a **[Person](http://schema.org/Person)**, **[Organization](http://schema.org/Organization)**, or **[Service](http://schema.org/Service)** to an **[OfferCatalog](http://schema.org/OfferCatalog)**.